# Can code running in the browser change that browser's configuration via about:flags

Tags: javascript, url, google-chrome-flags

Since Chrome and other browser's configuration flags are accessible via a URL, and the configuration is done typically within a web page, I was wondering if it presented a security vulnerability.

I was thinking it might be exploitable by a specifically-formed URL, such as

```
chrome://flags/javascript:handleEnableExperimentalFeature(Displaylist2Dcanvas, enable)
```

or by a bookmarklet-style javascript that loads and manipulates the flags page? I've tried to do this but it didn't work; I'm not sure if that's because I did it wrong, or because it just isn't vulnerable to that type of attack.

Comment: `I've tried to do this but it didn't work;` seeing your javascript code might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot do that. Just imagine if people could edit chrome flags via URL, it would be a disaster. Unless you write a chrome extension or some other client side application to change said chrome flag, you can't do that.